# How do I back up and restore a SQL Azure database?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

How do I back up and restore a SQL Azure database?

For that matter, how do I back up and restore an entire Azure account?  Let's suppose I am working at a company and I buy a 3 month trial account before my company comes onboard and says that there is a corporate account for me to work on?  How do I move all my stuff from one account to another?

Comment: One option for backup would be Red Gate cloud services : http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-azure-backup/

Comment: You can export and import to blob storage, which is basically a backup and restore. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh335292.aspx

Comment: I have managed to use the sql management studio to move the tables from one database to the new one after I created the new database online with SQL Azure. I tried all sorts of sync steps and downloads but in the end I just did this easy step by hand.

Comment: You have a free utility called Enzo Backup that provides SQL Azure backup/restore capabilities. The newer version (currently in Beta) allows you to backup/restore Azure Tables as well.  http://www.bluesyntax.net/backup.aspx